# How to design a power switching circuit using a photo-interrupter

Tags: phototransistor, coil

Okay. I'm completely at a loss here. I was trying to design a switching circuit for a 3A load (Solenoid) using a photo-interrupter. I got to about here:
[image]

But I have no idea what to look for in my parts. I plan to use [these](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5A-LED-Drive-Power-Supply-Module-Step-Down-CVCC-75W-Lithium-Battery-Charger-/400695001209?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5d4b488079&autorefresh=true) as the current limiters, and I have to use [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10-Pieces-5-16-Slot-PCB-Photo-Interrupter-Sensor-HY860H-/171325143377?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27e3c63951) as the photo-interrupter. I was thinking I could set one of the current limiters to the specifications of the photo-interrupter, but I don't know if it would work. (I really hope it would.)

As for the transistor, I was thinking of finding an pnp switching transistor that can carry 3A without overheating, but I've never been transistor shopping before, so I don't know what to look for in the specs. Also, I don't know what to set the current for the... Transistor collector? I was thinking of looking for something that switches at the same input current for the phototransistor, so when current stops flowing through the phototransistor, it goes through the collector.

I plan to have a coil of wire as the load, with a total resistance of about 1.213Ω.

Can anyone tell me if my plan will work? Also, if so, where to look for parts? I tried Ebay and Amazon, but neither have any interactive spec chart for Transistors.

Comment: Is it a coilgun?

Comment: **Gasp** Yes, and no. Yes, I am building an accelerator(well, this one circles back, so) and no. I am not building a coilgun/Gauss rifle etc. What I am building is a mock-up version of the accelerator at CERN. My design accelerates ball bearings and smashes them together. (A major difference from CERN being, I am not smashing protons, and my accelerator ring is 4' across)

Comment: I think the name "coilkid" was a clue

Comment: Lol, yup. This is for a group of people I help with physics, and also I get the added benefit of being able to say I have an accelerator in my basement.

Comment: Digikey has my favorite search engine for parts. (no comment about the rest.)

Comment: As folks said in your very *first question* about this, *design* the solenoid and power supply together to make it easier. Use a voltage that supplies the solenoid enough power, and wind the solenoid so that it does not tend to destroy itself. Complexity has been introduced to solve that mismatch. Switch the solenoid using a MOSFET. Choose N or P channel to make things easier. The photo-interrupter needs a current limiting resistor. The phototransistor needs a 2nd resistor to 'create' a voltage to switch the MOSFET. *Get the fundamental design 'right' first, then the rest will be simpler*.

Comment: @gbulmer I should never had said I was designing the solenoid. Please forget that. Thinner wire/more turns are _not and option_. The _only_ thing I can change is current. And don't get offended and say "What?! Why?!"

Comment: @CoilKid - I'm not offended. I am only trying to help you. There is no rule which says you have to accept.

Comment: @gbulmer I didn't say you were offended, I just asked you not to be. Anyway, thank you _very_ much for all the assistance

Answer (score 1):

It's not a great circuit. The PNP transistor would not switch on fully so I'd use an NPN with the emitter grounded - this way, current into the base turns the transistor on to about 0.1 volt across collector and emitter and wastes less power.

Having said all that I'd use an N channel MOSFET that maybe switches on to a few millivolts.

Comment: If I were to use an N channel MOSFET, would it work well?

Comment: It'd work a whole lot better than the PNP but your question is very subjective because it might work so well it could fry your 1.213 ohm solenoid from an 11.4 volt supply if the current limiter didn't work.

Comment: Also, where could I find this part? Like I said Amazon and Ebay weren't very helpful.

Comment: Well the limiter **should** work. I asked several questions here on EE.SE. The stuff I came up with would have wasted several W of power, but the current limiter I linked, uses switching at several mH to control current/voltage.

Comment: A switching current limiter will work pretty good. Also don't forget a reverse biased diode across the coil to kill off the energy spike when the transistor switches off. Requesting recommendations on actual components are a bit frowned upon.

Comment: A reverse biased diode? I think I'm gonna have to go Google that. Also, I can't change the photo-interrupter(The gap has to be that size, and that's the only model with that size gap), I don't want to change the current limiters, so I guess what I'd like to know is... Would it work well with an 'N channel MOSFET', and where can I find an online electronics store that carries them? I don't need anyone to tell me the component, but knowing where to look would be helpful.

Comment: Digikey, Farnell, RS are ones I've used in the UK but are available abroad I reckon

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I think I've heard of Digikey.. I don't remember where though.

Comment: There will be a lot of N channel MOSFETs to choose from on Digikey (or wherever) and just using any old MOSFET you come across on ebay is probably a guaranteed way to pick the wrong one. I recommend you do some research on how to choose the right MOSFET for your application. It's been asked on this stack exchange more than once.

Comment: @Andyaka Doing some research, I can't seem to find anything that switches after a few millivolts. The best I can find is _one_ that switches at 250mV I believe. Seeing as my phototransistor will burn out at more than _20_ mV I think I'm either out of luck, or in the wrong place.

Comment: That said, do you people on EE.SE know where I can ask one of those questions involving the words "Does anyone happen to know where I can find..."?

Answer (score 0):

(This should perhaps just be a comment, as it only provides a partial answer, but I wanted the drawing...)

You don't need one of the LED power supply modules you lined to for the photo-interrupter.

Electrically, the photo-interrupter is two independent parts - the IR LED, and the photo-transistor.

You should treat the IR LED as you would any other LED - just use a series resistor to limit the current.  Unfortunately, the data for the opto-interrupter doesn't give a forward voltage for the LED, but a 4N35 opt-isolator has a typical forward voltage of 1.3 volts, so I'll use that. The maximum LED current for the photo_interrupter is 50 mA, so I'll use 40 mA (I don't like using maximum values...).  since you have an 11.4V supply, the series resistor will be (11.4 - 1.3)/0.04 = 252 ohms - next higher standard value is 270 ohms, which will dissipate .4 watts, so you need a 1/2 watt resistor, or two 130 ohm 1/2 watt in series.

What you do with the photo-transistor depends on what follows it to switch the actual coil current.  I've shown two possible connections for the photo-transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM26u7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since the photo-trasistor will conduct when it is illuminated by the LED, OUT1 will be normally low, and will go high when the path from the LED is blocked.

OUT2 will normally be high, but will go low when the light path is blocked.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate the assistance. I have a design in mind for my circuit, and I _believe_ all that is left is for me to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be a phototransistor going into a comparator driving a MOSFET (sourcing the solenoid).

With this solution, you could adjust the reference on the comparator to change the sensitivity.